# How to produce an answer in the same row after click on 'Click to answer' button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am not to familiar with javascript, jquery etc. I need help to find out how to after click on the button, pop out filed where I can enter answer for specific question, and after that to show under that question(in same row). Also you can check that here http://jsfiddle.net/bobouch/thbnZ/1/

```
.table {
width: 99%;
color:#333333;
background-color: #E0E0E0;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #999999;
border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 20px;
font: 14px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

table , th {
background-color: #F08200;
padding: 8px;
border: 0px solid;
border-color: #E0E0E0;
color:#ffffff;
 }

table th:first-child {
width: 10%; 
}
table th:nth-child(2) {
width: 80%; 
}
table th:last-child {
width: 100px; 
}

table, tr {
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

table tr:hover {
background-color: #D4D4D4;
}

table, td {
text-align: center;
border: 0px solid;
padding: 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #E0E0E0;

}
```

//html

```
<table class='table'><th>Id</th><th>Question</th><th>Date</th><th>Answer</th>

<tr>
<td>
1
</td>
 <td>
 Some question here1
</td>
<td> 
Date
</td>
<td>
<button onclick='myFunction()'>Click to answer</button>
</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
2
</td>
<td>
 Some question here2
</td>
<td> 
Date
</td>
<td>
<button onclick='myFunction()'>Click to answer</button>
</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
3
</td>
<td>
 Some question here3
</td>
<td> 
Date
</td>
<td>
<button onclick='myFunction()'>Click to answer</button>
</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes, i few this. I found something on W3, but is not what i want..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pure javascript you can use some function parameters to do what you would like.

Something like this:

HTML

```
<h3 align="center">After hiting the Click button, i need to pop out field where i can answer specific question? How to produce an answer in the same row under each question </h3>
<table class='table'><th>Id</th><th>Question</th><th>Date</th><th>Answer</th>

<tr>
<td>1</td>
 <td id='q1'>Some question here1</td>
<td>Date</td>
 <td><button onclick="clickMe('First Question', 'q1');" type="button">Click to answer</button></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td id="q2">Some question here2</td>
<td>Date</td>
 <td><button onclick="clickMe('Second Question', 'q2');" type="button">Click to answer</button></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td id="q3">Some question here3</td>
<td>Date</td>
 <td><button onclick="clickMe('Third Question', 'q3');" type="button">Click to answer</button></td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clickMe(Question, id)
{
var QuestionPrompt = prompt(Question,"Type your answer here...");

if (QuestionPrompt!==null)
  {
      var curText = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
      var newText = curText + "<br/>" + QuestionPrompt;
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = newText;
  }
}
</script>
```

The onclick events send the question text and the id of the cell you want to put the answer in. The javascript function shows a simply input box and takes the answer and appends it to the cell with the question.

Not pretty or complicated, but it gets the job done. You could improve it in a lot of different ways.

Comment: Thanks. But, after adding some text, and after pressing Ok, text (answer) go nowhere, i mean it is not in same cell (td) like question.

Comment: The example works just fine for me. Try an in-browser de-bugger to see what's going on. You can access it by pressing f12 and if you're using Chrome or Firefox it will flag JS errors for you.

Comment: That table is in some php file and everything is ECHO-ed i hope that is not a problem. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Did you add id's to the php file? If not it won't work. If that's not the problem I'd have to see the php file to help.

Comment: Yes, i added id into php file but with single quotes, because double won't working. Do I need to put another question or just to send you php file directly here. (i am new here..)

Comment: If the php file isn't large, you should add it to your original post.